# Как отсортировать JSON файл

Tags: javascript, json, веб-программирование

Посылается запрос и мне надо отсортировать данные из **json** в порядке убывания.

```js
 $.ajax({
        url: './php/response.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $('#team-row_stat').html('');
            $(result).each(function(index, item) {
                if(item.stage > 5) {
                    item.stage = "закончила все этапы";
                } else {
                    item.stage = `находится на ${item.stage} этапе`;
                }

            $('#team-row_stat').append(`

            <div class="team-stat">${item.team} команда ${item.stage}</div>

            `);
})
        }
    });
```

Сортировать нужно поле **stage**

```html
[{"id":"two","team":"Красная","stage":"1","ch1":"0","ch2":"0","ch3":"0","ch4":"0","ch5":"0","dis1":"0","dis2":"0","dis3":"0","dis4":"0","dis5":"0"},{"id":"four","team":"Белая","stage":"1","ch1":"0","ch2":"0","ch3":"0","ch4":"0","ch5":"0","dis1":"0","dis2":"0","dis3":"0","dis4":"0","dis5":"0"},{"id":"five","team":"Фиолетовая","stage":"1","ch1":"0","ch2":"0","ch3":"0","ch4":"0","ch5":"0","dis1":"0","dis2":"0","dis3":"0","dis4":"0","dis5":"0"},{"id":"six","team":"Розовая","stage":"1","ch1":"0","ch2":"0","ch3":"0","ch4":"0","ch5":"0","dis1":"0","dis2":"0","dis3":"0","dis4":"0","dis5":"0"},{"id":"seven","team":"Оранжевая","stage":"1","ch1":"0","ch2":"0","ch3":"0","ch4":"0","ch5":"0","dis1":"0","dis2":"0","dis3":"0","dis4":"0","dis5":"0"}]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно указал вам @Alexey Ten нужно добавить сортировку

```
 $(result).sort((a,b)=>(+a.stage) - (+b.stage)).each(function(index
```

Думаю не трудно определить место которое нужно поменять